# Changes in EditText doesn't change StateFlow data over databinding

Tags: android, data-binding, viewmodel

I have an issue with databinding and StateFlow. View and model is binded together and when I input the data into edit text I do not see this changes in corresponded variable in viewmodel. Here is the code:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="model"
            type="ru.home.swap.ui.profile.ProfileViewModel" />
        <variable
            name="provider"
            type="ru.home.swap.providers.PersonProvider" />
    </data>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/blue_dark">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/contact_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingStart="24dp"
                android:paddingEnd="24dp"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/sign_in"
                >

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/contact"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:hint="Enter your cell or email"
                    android:text="@{model.name}"
                    tools:text="+7 910 900 87 70" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</layout>
```

ViewModel

```
private val _name = MutableStateFlow<String>("")
val name: StateFlow<String> = _name

fun createAnAccount() {
    Log.d(App.TAG, "Update name $name")
}
```

Linking view and model in fragment

```
binding.model = viewModel/*viewModel.uiState.value*/
binding.lifecycleOwner = this
binding.confirm.setOnClickListener {
    viewModel.createAnAccount()
}
```

I checked the documentation and all [looks fine](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/observability#lifecycle-objects)

Do you see an issue here?

Answer (score 3):

You’re not using `=` in text attribute that's why it is one way data binding. to make it Two way data binding you need to use `=` like this.

```
android:text="@={model.name}"
```

Try this now it should work.
[Two Way Databinding Documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way)

Comment: Thank you for point out on this. It is essential, but it is not enough. Compiler complains on this method ' cannot be inverted, so it cannot be used in a two-way binding'. I could make _state public and refer it in view - it will work, but it is different from what I am trying to achieve. We should not share encapsulated fields.

Comment: Did you check this documentation it might help. [Tow Way Databinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way)

Comment: Yes, I did. I doesn't cover this case. At this moment I see to break encapsulation if I want to continue with StateFlow and data binding.

Comment: model.name is of type StateFlow, which is read-only, so it makes sense you cannot have two way binding on it.